# Is $QT=T|_{N(T)^{\perp}}$, for linear operator $T:H_1\to H_2$ and orthog0nal projection $Q: H_2\to \overline{R(T)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inverse-problems

Let $T: H_1\to H_2$ be a bounded linear operator, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Hilbert spaces. Let $Q$ be the orthogonal projection of $H_2$ onto $\overline{R(T)}$. Is it correct to say that $QT=T^\#$, where $T^\#=T|_{N(T)^{\perp}}$

Comment: Not at all. The operator on the RHS is only defined on $N(T)^\perp$, while the LHS is defined on $H_1$. The equality only holds if $N(T) = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  All you are doing by taking $QT$ is changing the codomain, if you intend $Q$ to have codomain $\overline{R(T)}$ (otherwise you are changing nothing). It won't change the domain.  If $x$ is nonzero and in $N(T)$, then $QTx=Tx=0$, while $T|_{N(T)^\perp}(x)$ doesn't exist because $x$ is not in the domain.